# xinput mouse device: separate x and y sensitivities

Tags: xorg, mouse, xinput

I've been trying out a trackball mouse and I find that it is entirely too sensitive, so I tune it down by setting its `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` to 1.5, I feel like this dials in the X axis fine, but my Y axis motions are underwhelming.

Simply put, is it possibly to configure X and Y sensitivities separately?

My environment is fairly stock Linux Mint 17.1, so Ubuntu-trusty–like, Debian, Gnome 3, and the rest of the stack that I am less familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

The setting that you need to change is the
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144).

In the following examples the mouse is device id=9 and the property number of the Coordinate Transformation Matrix (of my mouse) is 144 as you can find out with `xinput list-props 9`
 

Set it to default: 
`xinput set-prop 9 144 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1`
Make X 5 times faster than Y: 
`xinput set-prop 9 144 5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1`
Make Y .2 times as fast as X: 
`xinput set-prop 9 144 1 0 0 0 .2 0 0 0 1`
Rotate 45 degrees: 
`xinput set-prop 9 144 .707 -.707 0 .707 .707 0 0 0 1`

Comment: Truly you must be a wizard. Give me a little time to confirm this, I don't use that particular mouse much but next I do I will give these a go! :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a Logitech M510. The speed in x direction was annoyingly faster than in y direction.

Setting the matrix like this worked like a charm:

```
xinput set-prop 11 136 0.6 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

11 is the ID of the mouse, 136 the ID of the mouse's Coordinate Transform Matrix. I obtained these values by calling

```
xinput
```

and then

```
xinput -list-props 11
```

Cheers!