# Linux how to use xinput to change Logitech mouse ERGO M575 speed and axis

Tags: linux, command-line, mouse, x-server, xinput

```
    #######  xinput --list  --short   ###### ###### ###### ###### ###### 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech ERGO M575                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)] ==============================
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Android Android                           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Android Android                           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]


###### xinput --list-props "Logitech ERGO M575"   ###### ###### ###### ###### ###### 
Device 'Logitech ERGO M575':
    Device Enabled (173):       1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (175):     1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (309):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (310):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (311):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (312):       0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (313):       0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (314):     2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (315):     2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (316):        0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (317):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (318):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (319):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (320): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (321): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (322):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (323):       1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (324):       1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (325): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (326): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (294): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (295):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (296):    0, 0
    Device Node (297):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (298):    1133, 16534
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (327):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (328):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (329):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (330):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (331):        1

xinput --list  --short   
xinput --list-props "Logitech ERGO M575"   

xinput --set-prop "Logitech ERGO M575"   "libinput Accel Speed"   0.9  ##########################========== speed up

### https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189180/xinput-mouse-device-separate-x-and-y-sensitivities
## no effect ##  xinput --set-prop "Logitech ERGO M575"   "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0       0 1 0       0 0 1
## no effect ##  xinput --set-prop "Logitech ERGO M575"   "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 100 0 0     0 100 0     0 0 100
xinput --set-prop "Logitech ERGO M575"   "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 93 -36 0    36  93 0     0 0 100  ##########################========== rotate the axis

Note:  X^^2 + Y^^2 == 100^^2    ======== why 93 match 36 : see following
100, 99, 98,    97, 96, 95,    94, 93, 92,    91, 90
0,   14, 20,    24, 28, 31,    34, 36, 39,    41, 43
```

Comment: I would recommend trying only using 0, 1, and -1 in transformation matrix for axis transformations. Then use `xset` or `libinput Accel Speed` for speed changes. For instance: `/usr/bin/xset m 7/6 0`